# Calculated field totals not correct in PowerPivot

Tags: excel, powerpivot

I have a basic data set with a ton of slicers that roughly looks like this:

```
       Hours    SpreadPerHr      Spread
       5.00        5.00          25.00
       10.00       2.00          20.00
       8.00       10.00          80.00
```

Where Spread is a calculated value where Spread = Hours*SpreadPerHour. The problem is, the totals for these columns follow this formula too, so it looks like this:

```
       Hours    SpreadPerHr      Spread
       5.00        5.00          25.00
       10.00       2.00          20.00
       8.00       10.00          80.00
Total: 23.00      17.00         391.00
```

And while the hours total up just fine, SpreadPerHour is dynamic and so Spread is as well. It is incorrect to say Total Spread = Total Hours * Total SpreadPerHour. Totals should be:

```
Total: 23.00      17.00         125.00
```

Is there a way I can make excel leave totals for Hours as-is, but sum the column for Spread instead of multiplying totals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I think you have in your Power Pivot Model:
[image]

You have a calculated measure for Spread, which I have labeled `SpreadCalc1`.  The problem with this is that it does the aggregation before it does the multiplication.  You need this operation to be done on a row-by-row basis and then aggregated.  So instead of a calculated measure, you need to create a calculated column and then sum that column.

[image]

The *column* I have labeled as `SpreadCalc` has the formula `=[Hours] * [SpreadPerHr]`. 
The calculated measure I called `Spread` is just `Sum([SpreadCalc])`.  You can see there that the total is 125 as desired instead of 391.

Comment: This looks right, but I don't understand the distinction. My Spread (which is [Hours]*[SpreadPerHr]) is a calculated measure in itself, its not present in the raw data, its a field I created in PowerPivot. I can create a new measure for sum([Spread]), but it errors out. Am I missing something?

Comment: The spread field wasn't in my original data set. You have to add the calculated field on the Power Pivot table, not as a calculated measure but as a [calculated column](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-a-calculated-column-in-power-pivot-HA102918362.aspx). Then change your calculated measure to sum the new column and it will work.  Here's a [good article](http://www.powerpivotpro.com/2013/02/when-to-use-measures-vs-calc-columns/) about when to use calculated columns vs calculated measures.

Comment: Ah, thank you! That really clarified it. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

I know this might be a bit redundant now, but I would suggest a slightly different approach.

Adding calculated columns in "small" tables is fine, but it can cause serious performance issues with large databases.

**So to solve your problem, I believe the "correct" way is to use *SUMX* function.**

It calculates the expression specifically for each row, which is exactly what you need. And it is smart as far as performance goes (no need to add calculated columns or perform any source-data manipulations).

If you use this formula (correct the name of the table / measures), you should get the desired results:

```
SUMX(YourTable, [Sum Hour] * [Sum SpreadPerHr])
```

[image]

Comment: I typically read that you want to [avoid SUMX](http://www.powerpivotblog.nl/tune-your-powerpivot-dax-query-dont-use-the-entire-table-in-a-filter-and-replace-sumx-if-possible/) because of performance issues, but [this blog post](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alberto_ferrari/archive/2011/10/26/sum-or-sumx-with-simple-intermediate-calculations-sumx-is-the-way-to-go.aspx) seems to confirm what you have said for simple calculations. Thanks for pointing that out. I think in this case the performance difference would be negligible, but I appreciate the new knowledge.

Comment: Thanks for the articles, will have a look at them.

Comment: This works wonderfully as well. This also seems a bit more straightforward. Thanks for the input!